# Difficulty understanding a piece of javascript code

Tags: javascript, timer

This piece of simple javascript code is a timer. that I want to put 0 before the second.
I put the if after the else, but the code didn't work, but when I put the code in the commented part, it worked, tell me why this happened?

```js
let minute = +prompt("Enter For Min :");
let second = +prompt("Enter For Sec :");

let timer = setInterval(function () {
  if (minute == 0 && second == 0) {
    document.body.innerHTML = `Time Out!`;
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    if (second < 10 && second.toString().indexOf(0) !== 0) {
      second = "0" + second;
    }//This code should paste to line 17 to work but why?
    --second;
    if (second == -1) {
      minute -= 1;
      second = 59;
    }
    //This Place
    document.body.innerHTML = `Timer ${minute} : ${second}`;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because numbers are numbers and strings are strings.  When you do this, you're turning `second` into a string:

```
second = "0" + second;
```

If you immediately display that string, it will include the pre-pended `0` character.  *However*, when you do this it becomes a number again:

```
--second;
```

So if you display the value it won't have any leading zero digits.

Overall, the structure of your code should be:

1. Gather input
2. Perform calculation
3. Display output

This part is calculation:

```
--second;
if (second == -1) {
  minute -= 1;
  second = 59;
}
```

This part is displaying output:

```
if (second < 10 && second.toString().indexOf(0) !== 0) {
  second = "0" + second;
}
document.body.innerHTML = `Timer ${minute} : ${second}`;
```

Keep them logically grouped as such.  Formatting the data for display (such as prepending characters to a numberic value) is part of displaying the output.